# JS display:none/block via dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with one select field like this:

```
<select onchange="toggle_form_element(this)" name="parts" id="parts">
    <option value="-">Please choose</option>
    <option value="0">Part 1</option>
    <option value="1">Part 2</option>
    <option value="2">Part 3</option>
</select>
```

Below this Form there are some div's, and I want do show / hide these div's based on the selected option in the dropdown field. Example:

```
<div id="Form1">Part 1</div>
<div id="Form2">Part 2</div>
<div id="Form3">Part 3</div>
```

My solution to get this working is the following js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_form_element(select) {
        if (select.value == '0') {
            document.getElementById('Form1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('Form2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form3').style.display = 'none';
        }else if (select.value == '1') {
            document.getElementById('Form1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('Form3').style.display = 'none';
        }else if (select.value == '2') {
            document.getElementById('Form1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form3').style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('Form1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form2').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('Form3').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now i would like to know if there is a way to make it shorter and simpler!? Because I have to add some more options to the select field.

Comment: Hi, someone posted this solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/dfQXP/ Now it is deleted. Is something wrong with this solution?

Comment: Does someone know a solution, if I have different values? I would like to use values like "Volvo", "Saab", etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function toggle_form_element(select) {
    var divSelect = select.value;
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (i == divSelect) {
            elements[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRhvx/

Comment: This solution will hide all the div in the document, at any level, unless its position in the list returned by getElementsByTagName is the same as select.value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle_form_element(select) {
    document.getElementById('Form1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Form2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Form3').style.display = 'none';
    //only for your example    
    document.getElementById('Form'+(parseInt(selected.value)+1)).style.display = 'block';

}
```

Comment: You could also pass the id of your form.. then just do a document.getElementById(select.value).style.display = 'block';

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, also available as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/6V4CC/)

While it is a bit involved at this simple level it demonstrates the approach of dynamically manipulating the CSS Rules for just the elements involved, that is #Form1 to #Form3.

This might scale better as complexity grows.

An additional static CSS Rule sets up an enclosing div not to display it content and children.

**CSS**

```
#hidingForms * {
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML+JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_form_element(select) {
        var lastStyleSheet, r, lastRule, myRule;
        myRule = '#' + select.value + ' { display: block; }';
        ss = document.styleSheets;
        if (ss.length > 0) {
            lastStyleSheet = ss[ss.length - 1];
            r = lastStyleSheet.cssRules;
            if (r.length > 0) {
                lastRule = r[r.length - 1];
                // debugger;
                if (lastRule && lastRule.cssText.match(/#Form/)) {
                    lastStyleSheet.deleteRule(lastStyleSheet.cssRules.length - 1);
                }
                if (select.value !== '-') {
                    lastStyleSheet.insertRule(myRule, lastStyleSheet.cssRules.length);
                }
                // console.dir(lastStyleSheet.rules);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<select onchange="toggle_form_element(this)" name="parts" id="parts">
    <option value="-">Please choose</option>
    <option value="Form1">Part 1</option>
    <option value="Form2">Part 2</option>
    <option value="Form3">Part 3</option>
</select>
<div id="hidingForms">
    <div id="Form1">Part 1</div>
    <div id="Form2">Part 2</div>
    <div id="Form3">Part 3</div>
</div>
```